# Firestore database only works every other time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a button on my page that looks like this

```
<Button
disabled={loading}
type="submit"
className="w-100 text-center mt-3"
onClick={() => {
    firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .doc("123")
    .set({ test: 123})
    .then(() => {
        setSuccessAlert("Updated user");
    })
    .catch(() => {
        setErrorAlert("Could not update user");
    });
}}
>
    Add user
</Button>
```

It uses bootstrap and typescript if that might give you a hint to what is wrong

If i put a console log in the onclick function it will always log it, but with the example above i need to press it twice for it to work. I've tested that its not just me being impatient, i've waited more than five minutes before pressing it again, but the instant i press it the second time it works.

Anyways if you know what i might be doing wrong please help me. Im lost

Comment: What does `setSuccessAlert` code look like?

Comment: its a useState hook

Comment: Okay. Where/how is the `successAlert` state used?

Comment: I figured out a solotion. It had nothing todo with the alerts tho

Answer (score 1):

It works when i declare a variable for `firebase.firestore().collection("users")` instead of calling it directly

so now the code looks like this:

```
const db = firebase.firestore().collection("users");

db.doc("123")
    .set({ test: 123})
    .then(() => {
        setSuccessAlert("Updated user");
    })
    .catch(() => {
        setErrorAlert("Could not update user");
    });
```

Comment: Seems odd to me, I'm curious why that is. I'm glad you found a solution though, thanks for sharing.